# Retrieve information from a multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I am stuck with a problem that I honestly can't get my head around it. I have looked at various possible solutions, implemented different code snippets including those from MSDN. Unfortunately all of the solutions just kept tap dancing around my problem and after a few hours of hacking at it I am finally left with the SOF avenue.

I am trying to retrieve information (POP3 Mail List) from a multidimensional ArrayList. The following code creates the ArrayList. I also added the values of the ArrayList during Debug mode.

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Function Name : List
' Credit to     : David Ross Goben
' Purpose       : Get the drop listing from the maildrop
'               :
' Returns       : Any Arraylist of POP3Message objects
'               :
' Typical telNet I/O:
'LIST            (submit)
'+OK Mailbox scan listing follows
'1 2532          (record index and size in bytes)
'2 1610
'3 12345
'.               (end of records terminator)
'*******************************************************************************
Public Function List() As ArrayList
    If Not IsConnected() Then Return Nothing '          'exit if not in TRANSACTION mode

    Me.Submit("LIST" & vbCrLf)                          'submit List request
    If Not CheckResponse() Then Return Nothing '        'check for a response, but if an error, return nothing
    '
    'get a list of emails waiting on the server for the authenticated user
    '
    Dim retval As New ArrayList                       'set aside message list storage
    Do
        Dim response As String = Me.Response            'check response
        If (response = "." & vbCrLf) Then               'done with list?
            Exit Do                                     'yes
        End If
        Dim msg As New POP3Message                      'establish a new message
        Dim msgInfo() As String = Split(response, " "c) 'separate by spaces, which divide its fields
        msg.MailID = Integer.Parse(msgInfo(0))          'get the list item number
        msg.ByteCount = Integer.Parse(msgInfo(1))       'get the size of the email message
        msg.Retrieved = False                           'indicate its message body is not yet retrieved
        retval.Add(msg)                                 'add a new entry into the retrieval list
    Loop
    Return retval                                       'return the list
End Function
```

Unfortunately I am unable to post an image of what the data looks like in debug mode but I will try a text representation of it:

```
'List  | Count = 125                        
'    |
'   (0) | Nothing
'   (1) | Nothing
'            |
'       Mail.POP3Message | Nothing
'                |
'           ByteCount | 492334
'           MailID    | 1
'           Message   | Nothing
'           Retrieved | False
```

When I checked to see if there are any items in the List, it returns a valid # of items.

```
'Get message list from pop3 server and populate dvgMsgList
        dgvMailSettings.Rows(12).Cells(1).Value = "retrieving LIST of messages"


        Try
            For Each msg In srvPOP3.List
                MsgBox("srvPOP3.List items = " & srvPOP3.List.Count)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error displaying Mail list")
        End Try
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on the topic for me as I really need to get to this data:

```
          |
       ByteCount   | 492334
       MailID      | 1
       Message     | Nothing
       Retrieved   | False
```

(Only the first two items are of interest to me)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: @Helrich: I am not able to retrieve the information from the List arraylist. I have a distinct feeling that I am not seeing something very obvious which is preventing me from getting my code correct. The way I interpret the array is a 3 dimensional array e.g: (1,1,4). I have tried a For Each obj In srvPOP3.List, I tried a For i = 0 to srvPOP3.List.Count - 1. For both instances I am not able to drill down the the data I need. I have tried to DirectCast, convert it to an array, etc. but to no avail, I end up getting different error message.

Comment: I would highly recommend abandoning `ArrayList` in favor of `List(Of POP3Message)`. That way, you can do your for each loop, and the iterator is already your desired `POP3Message` type, and you can access your data with `obj.ByteCount` etc.

Comment: Let me try that and report back in a few. Thanks for the heads up so far.

Comment: I tried your suggestion although I got an Object reference error, it would have involved recoding the function to achieve the desire syntax.

However, one thing you mentioned was the "obj.ByteCount" and by changing my "For Each" loop I was able to get the information I needed.

Comment: ... this is the corrected code:

Try
                    For Each msg In srvPOP3.List
                        MsgBox("Bytes = " & msg.ByteCount)
                    Next

Comment: So you found a solution to this problem? If you did posting your solution below would let people know it was solved.